# Replacing all instances of a string that are in a list? (similar to re.sub)

Tags: python, string, python-re

I'm looking for a quick easy way to remove all instances of a string that are in a specified list. For example, in Python, let's take the string.punctuation list, and then modify it by removing a few characters (not fixed, this list may change); what's a neat way to do this? Ideally I'd like something as quick and simple as re.sub()

Below is some code the long way:

```
import string

exclude = set(['./,'])
new_set = list(set(string.punctuation).difference(exclude))
special_char = "##"

process_text = "hello, this is to be removed !?"
final_text = ""
for char in process_text:
    if char in new_set:
       final_text += special_char
    else:
       final_text += char

return final_text
```

Comment: Your `exclude` initialization should be `exclude = set('./,')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is close, with a few comments:

- The argument of `difference()` should be `set('./,')` rather than `set(['./,'])` to ensure that the characters to be excluded are added as individual elements of the set (rather than having the entire string `'./,'` added to the set as a single element)
- Because you intend to use `new_set` to check for inclusion of characters in a loop, it will be more efficient to keep it as a `set` rather than convert to a `list`
- Because `str` is an immutable type, it will be more efficient to build the result using a mutable sequence such as `list` and convert to `str` as a final step

```py
from string import punctuation

exclude = './,'
new_set = set(punctuation).difference(set(exclude))

process_text = "hello, this is to be removed !?"
final_text = ''.join([c for c in process_text if c not in new_set])
```

Input: `hello, this is to be removed !?`

Output: `hello, this is to be removed`

---

Alternative solution using `re.sub()`:

```py
from string import punctuation
import re
exclude = set('./,')
process_text = "hello, this is to be removed !?"
final_text = re.sub('[' + re.escape(''.join([c for c in punctuation if c not in exclude])) + ']', '', process_text)
```

Explanation:

- create a regex pattern with all the characters to be removed (appropriately escaped using [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape)) enclosed in square brackets (see `[]` within [`Regular Expression Syntax`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax))
- call [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with this pattern, with `''` as the replacement string (argument `repl`), and with `process_text` as the string to be modified.

Comment: Do you need any more help with your question?